# Generate Embeddings with Keras

Tags: keras

I am trying to generate embeddings with keras using LSTM autencoder. I got my hand on the model, but I am not sure how to get embeddings for my data. Embeddings are supposed to be latent representation of original input data which has shape in my case of `(847, 147)`.

```
model = keras.Sequential(name="LSTMAE")

#Encoder
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(128, activation='tanh', 
                             input_shape=(847, 147), 
                             kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.0000001), 
                             return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64, 
                             activation='tanh',
                             return_sequences=False))

model.add(keras.layers.RepeatVector(train_copy.shape[0]))

#Decoder
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(64, 
                             activation='tanh',
                             return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(128, 
                             activation='tanh',
                             return_sequences=True))

model.add(keras.layers.TimeDistributed(keras.layers.Dense(train_copy.shape[1])))
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, clipnorm=1.0, clipvalue=0.5), loss='mse')
model.summary()
```

Please let me know if you need more details in case anything is vague about my que

Comment: what's the shape of your input data? is it 2D (847, 147) ?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani. Thank you. `input_shape=(847, 147)`

Comment: If it's 2D there is no sense to use LSTM